# Correct directory for Oracle installation on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, fhs

What is the best directory to install Oracle on Linux box? **/srv**, **/opt**, **/usr/local**?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use OFA then read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_ofa.htm#BABHAIIJ)

OFA = Oracle Optimal Flexible Architecture standard. The standard is a set of configuration guidelines created to ensure well organized Oracle installations that are easier to maintain

Comment: +1 for OFA.  It makes life easier for those DBAs that come after you.

Comment: Exactly, you can endlesly discus all the recomendations in OFA. But the main reason to use OFA is that database servers are more easily maintained by other DBA's because we all use the same setup.

Answer (score 1):

Program or data?

For data, where-ever your RAID is mounted.

For program, /opt is OK.